# UDP Socket: How to determine when the available bytes are a full datagram

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

I have a .NET Socket (`System.Net.Sockets.Socket`) which I want to use for UDP (connectionless communication). I want to receive datagrams with polling, that is, I want to call the `Available` method to check whether a datagram is available. If it is, I call `Receive` to receive it without blocking. If it is not, I wait and poll again later. But now my problem is the following:

`Available` only returns how many bytes are available to be read without blocking. It does not tell whether these bytes are enough to form a full datagram. I do not know how big the datagrams I receive will be, so I cannot hardcode this check to a certain number.

How can I determine when one datagram ends and the next starts?

Comment: UDP only delivers complete datagrams, the number of bytes available are a complete packet. This is not like TCP which is a streaming protocol.

Comment: Why are you fixed on this polling approach? Simply call Receive and a packet will be given to you.

Comment: @usr: The receive is done in a game loop. It is no fun if your game stalls just because it is waiting for a packet.

Comment: The usual approach is to use async IO and always have one read outstanding. Be notified of packets instead of polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Philip says, with UDP you either get the entire datagram, or not at all. If the socket reports data is available, it should be the entire amount of a datagram (or some combination of datagrams).

That said, in your post you say you want to use polling to receive the data. That's a poor choice for any implementation. .NET's network I/O has very good asynchronous implementation models you can use (including wrapping the socket in a `NetworkStream` object and using `ReadAsync()` with the `async`/`await` feature of C# 5), which would be a much better choice.

In addition, you should be very sure that UDP is in fact the protocol you want to use. It is inappropriate for nearly all run-of-the-mill network applications, due to its unreliability. There is no guarantee that:

- Any data you send will be received. Datagrams are permitted to be dropped by the network.
- The data that is received will be received in the same order in which it was sent. Delivery of datagrams may be reordered by the network.
- The data that is received will be unique. The network is permitted to deliver the same datagram multiple times.

For most network applications, the business layer needs to be protected against these types of failures, which means adding your own layer of reliability between the business layer and the network layer. I.e. reinventing TCP.

It is *much* easier to impose a messaging paradigm on TCP than it is to impose a reliable paradigm on UDP, and for this reason it is in most cases more appropriate to use TCP for all network I/O than UDP.

Comment: The code is used in a game. Games are one of the few scenarios where you usually do not want all the features of TCP. Because of this, I also opted for the polling, as the game loop must be single threaded and network packages must be handled in each loop iteration. I could have used asyncs that store the packages into concurrent queues which are then read from the game loop. But then I still have polling; I just poll the queues instead of the sockets.

Comment: There is actually quite a bunch of UDP applications flying around. For instnace TFTP is based on UDP. I use it quite often actually. SNMP is also UDP , use very often as well. In short I don't agree with the last part of this answer. UDP is a lot simpler to implement any messaging protocol because it is not streamed. TCP code is a lot more cumbersome. TCP servers are a lot more complex than UDP servers.

Comment: @gexicide: "Games are one of the few scenarios where you usually do not want all the features of TCP" -- it depends on the game. But I've seen too many games that fail in the Internet scenario because UDP was used when reliability was needed, and the game developer failed to make their UDP communications reliable. Some game data becomes quickly out of date and/or can be safely processed multiple times in arbitrary order, and for this UDP is fine. But there other game data (even in the same game) which require reliability, and for this TCP should be used.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: you are welcome to your opinion. TFTP and SNMP are both examples of protocols with very specific needs; for example, broadcasting. Note however that TFTP is very simple and rarely used outside of a LAN; UDP through conventional NAT routers can be a pain. I whole-heartedly disagree with the broad claim that "TCP servers are a lot more complex than UDP servers". A UDP server that is reliable requires an implementation _at least as complex_ as that for a TCP server, and the network I/O classes in .NET make TCP very easy to do correctly and simply.